# Cannot compile curl and libgcc as a static library in MinGW/CLion (c++)

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, mingw, libcurl

I am trying to compile curl and libgcc as a static library so I would not have to include dll files with my program. I am having problems with `libcurl.dll` not found when I run the executable through command prompt. Also, there is another error `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` not found.

It works when I put the dll files in the same folder as executable but that is not what I am really fond of. I have put `-DCURL_STATICLIB` in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` as suggested here:

`https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html`

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(ham)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32 -DCURL_STATICLIB)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -std=c++14 -LC:/curlx86 -lcurl")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lwinmm")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive")


project(untitled3)
add_executable(ham Ham/ham.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ham "C:/curlx86/libcurl.dll.a")
```

I want my program to run without including any extra dll files. What should I do ?

`Edit`
When I use
`target_link_libraries(ham "C:/curlx86/libcurl.dll.a")`

I get these errors.

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `libssh2_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to`libssh2_exit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `nghttp2_version'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to`nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_send'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x31d): undefined reference to`nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x3c0): undefined reference to `nghttp2_pack_settings_payload'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x4bd): undefined reference to`nghttp2_session_resume_data'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x51c): undefined reference to`nghttp2_strerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to `nghttp2_priority_spec_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x614): undefined reference to`nghttp2_submit_priority'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/curlx86/libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x621): undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_send'

Comment: File `.dll.a` is an import file for a **dynamic library**, this is not a *static library*. You need to link with `libcurl.a` or so, without `.dll` part.

Comment: Hi I tried it and I have edited my results above. I get alot of errors when I use `libcurl.a`. I had to delete most of the errors from text above because there were ton of them. I am guessing I am missing `ssl` and other libraries alike.

Comment: Yes, when link with the *static* library you need **manually** to link with all libraries from which given library depends. Unlike to *dynamic* libraries, *static* ones don't store list of required libraries.

Answer (score 2):

#### Part 1. Setting up openssl v1.1.1b

1. Download the **openssl v1.1.1b** package (not the installer)
2. Download and install **MSYS2**
3. Open `msys.exe` (not `mingw32.exe` or `mingw.exe`)
4. Run this command to install perl and other packages:

   ```
   pacman -S make perl msys2-devel libcrypt-devel perl-CPAN mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
   ```
5. Now close `msys.exe` and open `mingw32.exe`
6. Change directory to wherever you extracted the openssl package, in my case it's this:

   ```
   cd "C:\Users\John\Downloads\openssl-1.1.1b\openssl-1.1.1b"
   ```

   Before continuing any further you have to add `#include <windows.h>` to these files underneath the directory:

   - `crypto\dso\dso_win32.c`
   - `crypto\init.c`
7. Run (this compiles openssl as a static library):

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=c:/OpenSSLx86 --openssldir=c:/OpenSSLx86 no-threads no-idea no-shared mingw
   ```
8. Run `make clean`
9. Run `make depend`
10. Run `make`
11. Run `make install`

#### Part 2. Building curl with openssl v1.1.1b

1. Download and extract the **curl** package
2. Change directory:

   ```
   cd "C:\Users\John\Downloads\curl\curl-7.65.0"
   ```
3. Edit `lib\curl_setup.h` and add the following lines to reduce the size of the compiled library by choosing only the options you will use. I will be using only the SMTP protocol, so I am disabling the others.

```c
#define CURL_DISABLE_TFTP
#define CURL_DISABLE_FTP
#define CURL_DISABLE_LDAP
#define CURL_DISABLE_TELNET
#define CURL_DISABLE_DICT
#define CURL_DISABLE_FILE
#define CURL_DISABLE_RTSP
#define CURL_DISABLE_POP3
#define CURL_DISABLE_IMAP
//#define CURL_DISABLE_SMTP
#define CURL_DISABLE_GOPHER
#define CURL_DISABLE_SMB
```

4. Set `OPENSSL_PATH = C:\OpenSSLx86` in these files:

- `lib\Makefile.m32`
- `src\Makefile.m32`

5. Run `make mingw32-ssl`
6. Now copy `libcurl.a` from `lib` to `C:\curlx86` and you are good to go.

Here is my final `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)     #curl
project(ham)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_compile_definitions(
        CURL_STATICLIB
        WITH_SSL=STATIC
)
#CURL_DISABLE_SMTP

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -m32")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -LC:/curlx86 -lcurl -LC:/OpenSSLx86/lib -lssl -LC:/OpenSSLx86/lib -lcrypto")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lwinmm -lcrypt32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lwinpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive") 


project(untitled3)
add_executable(ham Ham/ham.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ham "C:/curlx86/libcurl.a"  "C:/OpenSSLx86/lib/libssl.a" "C:/OpenSSLx86/lib/libcrypto.a")
```